# Invoking a PhotoShop JSX script with arguments via Python

Tags: python, arguments, jsx, photoshop

I have a JSX PhotoShop script that I want to invoke via python. I have successfully invoked the script without sending any arguments, but when I try to send arguments, I have trouble retreiving them. The data I want to send is a JSON string, but I have also tried saving the JSON via python and just sending the path via the script - still no result.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

I am invoking the script via python using:
`subprocess.run([f"{photoshop_path}", "-r", f'$.evalFile("{script_path}")', f'-f="{json_file_path}"'], shell=True)`

And I try to retreive the data in JSX using:
`var data = app.scriptArgs.get("f")`

Thanks all

Comment: I think that scriptArgs is InDesign DOM only. You might be able to load your results with $.evalFile